Interpretation of generalized eigenvalues, matrix distance, information geometry
This question is about how generalized eigenvalues of two covariance matrices relate to the discriminability of their associated Gaussian distributions.
The generalized eigenvalue problem for two symmetric matrices $(\pmb{A}, \pmb{B})$ is $\pmb{A}\pmb{\Phi} = \pmb{B}\pmb{\Phi}\pmb{\Lambda}$ where $\pmb{A}$ and $\pmb{B}$ are symmetric $n \times n$ matrices, $\pmb{\Phi} = [\Phi_1, ..., \Phi_n]$ is an $n \times n$ matrix whose columns are the generalized eigenvectors $\Phi_i$, and $\pmb{\Lambda}= \mathrm{diag}(\lambda_1, ..., \lambda_n)$ is a diagonal matrix with the generalized eigenvalues (where $\lambda_i \geq \lambda_{i+1}$). The result is the same as the regular eigenvalues and eigenvectors of matrix $\pmb{B}^{-1}\pmb{A}$. Because $\pmb{B}^{-1}\pmb{A}$ is typically not symmetric (although it's still positive definite), the eigenvectors $\Phi_i$ are not necessarily orthogonal.
The generalized eigenvalue problem relates to the discriminability between distributions. Say that vector $\pmb{x}$ is distributed as a mixture of two distributions, indexed by variable $y \in \{1, 2\}$. How well can we determine which of the two distributions generated an instance of $\pmb{x}$? We could use a quadratic feature given by $(\pmb{v}^T\pmb{x})^2$, where $||\pmb{v}||=1$. A measure of how well $\pmb{v}$ discriminates the two distributions is given by the ratio of the expected values
$$R(\pmb{v}) = \frac{\mathbb{E}\left[ (\pmb{v}^T \pmb{x})^2 | y=1\right]}{\mathbb{E}\left[ (\pmb{v}^T \pmb{x})^2 | y=2\right]} = \frac{\pmb{v}^T\pmb{\Sigma_1}\pmb{v}}{\pmb{v}^T\pmb{\Sigma_2}\pmb{v}}$$
It turns out that the $\pmb{v}$ maximizing $R$ is given by the first generalized eigenvector of $(\pmb{\Sigma_1},\pmb{\Sigma_2})$, and that the value of $R$ is given by its associated eigenvalue (check the reference above). Thus, the generalized eigenvalues say something about how discriminable two distributions are by a quadratic discriminator.
Interestingly, for 0-centered Gaussians, the Fisher-Rao distance between distributions (whose metric measures how discriminable local changes to the distribution are) is given by $\sum_{i=1}^{i=n} (\log \lambda_i)^2$ where the $\lambda_i$ are the generalized eigenvalues. This is also the Affine invariant distance in the Symmetric Positive Definite (SPD) matrices manifold.
So, given all the above, my question is as follows. It is clear how the individual $\lambda_i$'s of a pair of covariance matrices reflects how discriminable their 0-mean Gaussians are along the corresponding $\Phi_i$. However, it is less clear to me what all the eigenvalues brought together represent. The quantity $\sum_{i=1}^{i=n} (\log \lambda_i)^2$ clearly summarizes something, and it is intuitive how it adds up how different from 1 the $\lambda_i$'s are. But I also wonder how the different $\Phi_i$ not being orthogonal comes into the interpretation. Is there something more rigurous that can be said about how the full set of generalized eigenvalues of a pair of covariances relates to their discriminability?

Look at the situation geometrically: choose a basis in which $B$ is the identity and go on from there.
